# Reducing volume of an audio device on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio

I have a [USB headset](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0015YKWW6) with a *very* loud amplifier, but low granularity in its gain control. In order to get comfortable audio, I have to reduce the individual application levels in the mixer to '1', and the master mixer to around '10'. Of course, new applications start out at '10', and immediately blast out my ears.

Is there a way to add a filter to cut down the volume some so I can get better control of it? That is, reduce the volume of '100' so I can work within a reasonable range.

Comment: Does it not work to just leave applications at 100% and reduce the overall system volume to wherever you want it? Should have the same effect.

Comment: @nhinkle, only if the master volume control is actually useful - I no longer have the headset in question, but at the time I had very little room to adjust the range in. As I said in the question, I reduced master volume to 10% and apps to 1%, and it was still loud - if I put apps to 100% then system volume would have to be at 1%, leaving me no range to fine-tune volume at all.

Answer (score 0):

Klite Mega codec pack has volume adjustment built into it if you are viewing movies and such.

Comment: While I'm aware that some codec packs (klite, CCCP included) include filters with gain control, that only works for movie playback. Even if I reduce the volume there, that just means I'll blast out my ears every time some random program makes a 'ding!' sound

Comment: I have same issue, and I usually turn down the "windows sounds" very low.  Also there is volume correction inside the speakers section of Win7 also, tried any of that?